# Lucene request : stemming with FrenchAnalyzer and QueryParser or TermQuery

Tags: lucene, stemming

I need to perform requests with stemming functionnality.
When the search term is "invention", both of these documents must be returned:
"Ils inventèrent le feu"
"L'invention est belle"

I use lucene 6.2.1 and my code follow this:

- The index is created with a IndexWriter populated with a
  FrenchAnalyser.
- The searched field is a stored text field.
- The request is performed with a QueryParser populated with a
  FrenchAnalyzer.

Currently documents are returned well if the search is "invent", but not with "invention". Am I missing something to perform stemmed request?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

The described method is good.

Actually, "inventions" is stemmed into "invention" and "inventer" is stemmed into "invent". That's what perturbed me.